# CsvHelper ByteArrayConverter NullValues problem

Tags: c#, .net-core, csvhelper

I'm having a bit of a problem with converting an empty (value is "NULL") `Key` field to a byte array with CsvHelper, i keep getting this exception:

```
CsvHelper.ReaderException: An unexpected error occurred.
---> System.FormatException: Could not find any recognizable digits.
at System.ParseNumbers.StringToInt(ReadOnlySpan`1 s, Int32 radix, Int32 flags, Int32& currPos)
at System.Convert.ToByte(String value, Int32 fromBase)
at CsvHelper.TypeConversion.ByteArrayConverter.HexStringToByteArray(String hex)
at CsvHelper.TypeConversion.ByteArrayConverter.ConvertFromString(String text, IReaderRow row, MemberMapData memberMapData)
at lambda_method(Closure )
at CsvHelper.Expressions.RecordCreator.Create[T]()
at CsvHelper.Expressions.RecordManager.Create[T]()
at CsvHelper.CsvReader.GetRecord[T]()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

The mapping is set up like this:

```
public sealed class ZaznamMapping : ClassMap<Zaznam>
{
    public ZaznamMapping(FileSettings configuration)
    {
        var nullValues = new[] { "NULL", "null", string.Empty };

        for (int i = 0; i < configuration.Count(); i++)
        {
            switch (configuration[i])
            {
                case Col.Ignore: continue;
                case Col.Id:     Map(m => m.Id).Index(i).TypeConverterOption.NullValues(nullValues); break;
                case Col.Idd:    Map(m => m.Idd).Index(i).TypeConverterOption.NullValues(nullValues); break;
                case Col.Data:   Map(m => m.Data).Index(i).TypeConverterOption.NullValues(nullValues); break;
                case Col.Key:    Map(m => m.Key).Index(i).TypeConverterOption.NullValues(nullValues); break;
                default: throw new NotSupportedException($"Mapping() - Unknown column \"{configuration[i].ToString()}\"!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And Zaznam class:

```
public sealed class Zaznam
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Idd { get; set; }
    public byte[] Data { get; set; }
    public byte[] Key { get; set; }
}
```

The value in file `Key` coluimn is literally `NULL` (as in string containing the letters "NULL"). Should not the ByteArrayconverter respect the `TypeConverterOptions`?

The questions being:

- **Am I doing something wrong?**
- **Should I be making my own converter instead?**

Comment: but your nullValues array contains empty string as well ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the null value logic wasn't added to `ByteArrayConverter`.  If you look at [`StringConverter`](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/master/src/CsvHelper/TypeConversion/StringConverter.cs), the same null logic is not in the `ConvertFromString` method for [`ByteArrayConverter`](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/4cf576ec5524f73fc7894232b23a5969acc48e46/src/CsvHelper/TypeConversion/ByteArrayConverter.cs). You should be able to create your own custom `TypeConverter` to add the logic and then register it for all `byte[]`.

```cs
public class NullByteArrayConverter : ByteArrayConverter
{
    public override object ConvertFromString(string text, IReaderRow row, MemberMapData memberMapData)
    {
        foreach (var nullValue in memberMapData.TypeConverterOptions.NullValues)
        {
            if (text == nullValue)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        return base.ConvertFromString(text, row, memberMapData);
    }
}
```

```cs
csv.Configuration.TypeConverterCache.AddConverter<byte[]>(new NullByteArrayConverter());
```